# Second monitor is not being detected on Ubuntu (Kubuntu) 19.10

Tags: drivers, graphics, multiple-monitors, display, intel-graphics

I have a Lenovo [M720s ThinKCentre Desktop PC](https://download.lenovo.com/pccbbs/thinkcentre_pdf/m720s_ughmm_en.pdf), Type 10SU, Model 10SUS9GM00, has the Intel UHD Graphics 630 graphics.

The detected monitor is connected to the Displayport port via an adapter (vga to DP). The undetected monitor is connected to the **VGA port**.

The boot is performed only if I choose the option **safe graphics** on the boot screen when starting LiveUSB (I am using UEFI mode)

Question: is this what is preventing the second monitor from being detected?

Comment: I added details in the description of my case. Thanks.

Comment: Page 4 of your hardware manual https://download.lenovo.com/pccbbs/thinkcentre_pdf/m720s_ughmm_en.pdf shows only one VGA video connector, #2 in the diagram, and two DisplayPort connects, #3 in the diagram. Which are you connecting to for each monitor? If both monitors are DisplayPort capable, what happens if you exchange the monitor cables at the back of the PC?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I updated the case description with a link for more information.

Comment: I updated the text to try to know if the problem of not detecting the second monitor is caused by the boot problem.

Comment: After a lot of research, I finally found that the problem of both the boot failure and the detection of the VGA monitor are in the **kernel version 5.3 specifically**.    
The references were [here](https://medium.com/@leonlyxl/vga-not-working-after-ubuntu-19-10-upgrade-fret-not-e409ca6aba) and [here](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=205133).        
Now that I have completed the research, I will post my machine tests here as soon as possible.    
I will have to proceed with the upgrade to the kernel >= 5.4 and I hope I don't need to include any kernel parameters in grub.